# Detecting faked pagerank

Tags: php, user-agent, pagerank

Does anyone know how I would go about detecting faked pagerank in a php script im writing to run checks on a domain?

I understand that PR is faked when someone sets up a specific 301 redirect to a high pr domain exclusively for googlebots, but dont know how I would mimic this to check (I guess I would need the exact user agent?)

Thanks

Comment: why is this down voted?  Looks like he is asking how to set up google's agent data in php

Comment: @Andrey: Probably because it wasn't appropriately tagged so it was hard to tell at a glance.

Comment: sometimes it's hard to tag a problem properly if you dont really know what the problem is yet! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use GoogleBot's UserAgent, and visit the site with a script (or even from your browser). (If from the script) check for the HTTP response code.

Google Bot UserAgent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

Comment: Thanks Ruel. Do you Think I should do this with Fopen?